GraalVM native image remote repository
Is it possible to use the Gradle GraalVM plugin to build a nativeImage to a remote repository directly, or are extra steps outside of that required?
For a specific example, I'd like to use a Github Action to build a nativeImage to an AWS ECR repository. At the moment, I know I can do the following for plugin configuration:
graalvmNative {
    binaries {
        named("main") {
            imageName.set( "123etc.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/some/repo" )
        }
    }
}

Normally, I would have simply acquired or passed-in ECR username/password credentials to something like Docker or Jib to finish pushing to the destination, but

In the GraalVM Gradle plugin documentation, I don't see any mention for that
In the GraalVM Github Action documnetation, I don't see any reference to that either

Thanks for any help!

Turns out my expectations were wrong; The GraalVM plugin itself doesn't actually do anything with containers, so that explains why I couldn't find anything!
Once that lightbulb went off I did quickly figure out how to configure/push the container (which, for posterity, was via the micronaut framework)
